# How to bind data in a link inserted to a v-html in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Here's my code:

```
<pre
                            class="pre-text-formatted feed mt-2"
                            v-html="post.description.length >= 200 ? post.description.substring(0,200) + `... <a @click='readMore' class='text-muted pull-right' href>...read more</a>` :  post.description">
                        </pre>
```

And here's the output:
[image]

The readMore method does not trigger its function.

Comment: u can't bind `v-html` directive, but in your code you can use simple conditional rendering

Answer (score 0):

you should try with [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), as below:

```
<pre
  class="pre-text-formatted feed mt-2">
  <template v-if="post.description.length >= 200">
    {{ post.description.substring(0,200) }}... 
    <a @click='readMore' class='text-muted pull-right' href>...read more</a>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    {{ post.description }}
  </template>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to change this to back end .

Answer (score 0):

Hello I personally don't like using v-html except in some rare cases. For this question I will suggest you render your templates conditionally. here's a sample that might help.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    post: {
       description: 'Hello you\'re awesome today.',
    },
  },
  methods: {
    readMore() {
      alert('You click read more');
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre
      class="pre-text-formatted feed mt-2">
      <template v-if="post.description.length >= 200">
        {{ post.description.substring(0,200)}} <a @click='readMore' class='text-muted pull-right' href>...read more</a>
      </template><template v-else>{{post.description}}</template>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to change this to back end .